Google Earth Engine Landsat cloud mask code origin
There are several similar instances of GEE cloud mask function code online that look like the following, from Cloud Mask Landsat 7 Tier 2 TOA :
var cloudMaskL457 = function(image) {
  var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
  // If the cloud bit (5) is set and the cloud confidence (7) is high
  // or the cloud shadow bit is set (3), then it's a bad pixel.
  var cloud = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 5)
                  .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 7))
                  .or(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 3));
  // Remove edge pixels that don't occur in all bands
  var mask2 = image.mask().reduce(ee.Reducer.min());
  return image.updateMask(cloud.not()).updateMask(mask2);
};

What is the purpose of 'mask2' here?
(The "Remove edge pixels that don't occur in all bands" comment seems somewhat vague)


What is the purpose of 'mask2' here?

It evaluates if there is any masked pixel in any band in this image, and remove the pixel whenever it found one. In other words, for any given pixel, even if other bands have a value, if one band exist with no value, the pixel (all bands) will be removed.
.mask() evaluates all bands in each pixel, and returns the same image with the same number of bands but with binary bands' value. In the new image, the bands values are assigned 1 when the band exist in the original image, and 0 if the band had no value  in the original image (masked).
.reduce(ee.Reducer.min()) returns, in each pixel, the minimum value across all bands. Here as applied after mask, it will returns 0 if there is any zero and 1 only if there is no 0.
The combination of these two will create "mask2" as a binary mask with the value 1 if no bands where masked and 0 if one or more bands are masked.
"the edge pixels" is probably referring to the edge of Landsat 457 scenes where this missing bands occurs. You can add one Landsat scene and inspect and observe the edge pixels to see what's happening. See a toy code here
You may also note that such masking should be applied with caution as it can easily remove valid pixels, if any other (sometime irrelevant) band was masked for any reason

Es_a, thank you! That is a good explanation of the code. I suspected this is what "mask2" was doing, but thought I might have missed something. I was using this mask function on LandSat data (LANDSAT/LE07/C02/T1_L2) and got lots of missing areas which seemed to be due to "mask2". Your "toy code" example exactly showed the same effect I was getting. For my purpose, I think it's safe to disable the "mask2" line in my code. Thanks again.
